# Windows 10 hibernation Insufficient system resources?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate

After the fall creators update when ever I try to put the PC into hibernation the screen turns black as usual but after a while it goes back to the lock screen , Also sleep and shutdown won't work unless I disable hibernation & hybrid shutdown.
when I tried hibernating the PC using the following command "shutdown /h" the same thing happens with the following message :
"Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.(1450)".

I used to have the same issue with the insiders build leading to the fall creators update and now I'm using a freshly installed version of the fall creators update with nothing installed but the GPU driver "R9 390x" but still getting the same thing.

Comment: How much RAM and free hard drive space do you have?

Comment: @AthomSfere 32GB ram , and 79.6GB free HDD space

Comment: Microsoft has a KB introducing the same error message, you could refer to their registry method to check result.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304101/backup-program-is-unsuccessful-when-you-back-up-a-large-system-volume

Comment: @Origami unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: same problem. Have not found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try:

1. Disable Hyper-V if it is enabled. From an administrator command prompt,

   ```
   bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off
   ```

   ([MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542202(v=vs.85).aspx); use `bcdedit` with no arguments to check the current setting) or just remove Hyper-V altogether (Control Panel/Programs/Turn Windows features on or off). If you actually need Hyper-V this is not really a solution...
2. If you're using a recent model Dell laptop, [reset the Real Time Clock](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln304892/how-to-reset-real-time-clock--rtc--to-recover-your-dell-xps--latitude-and-precision-pc?lang=en) (see [this thread](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19678716)).

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread that solved exactly the same problem: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79e2eb35-bc07-4975-9e83-070f1d732a9e/unable-to-hibernate-after-fall-creators-update?forum=win10itprogeneral

I and the users in that thread all seem to have HP machines. The fix requires a BIOS configuration change:
under the advanced page > secureboot configuration change "legacy support enable and secure boot disable" to "legacy support disable and secueboot enable (or secureboot can remain disabled)".